# Fortran 95 double summation does not output correctly

Tags: sum, fortran, fortran95

I am trying to write a double summation in Fortran 95, however, I never seem to get the correct output. It always seems to output Fortran's very small real numbers. Here is my code:

```
    program summation
    implicit none
    integer::i,j,m,n
    real::s,s1
    s1=0
      do i=1,100
        do j=1,100
          s1=s1+(1/((i**2)+(j**2)))
        end do
        s=s1+s
      end do
    print*, s
    end program summation
```

The end value of s should be around 6.4, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initially set `s`. So you get complete garbage.

You should re-set `s1` to 0 in every iteration after you make `s = s + s1`.

You also divide 1 by a larger integer, so the result is always integer 0. You must make one of tye terms `real`. In my example I make 1 real by using `1.`.

So

```
s=0

do i=1,100
 s1=0
 do j=1,100
   s1=s1+(1./((i**2)+(j**2)))
 end do
 s=s1+s
end do

print*, s
```

is possible, but why not just sum everything into one accumulator?

```
s=0

do i=1,100
 do j=1,100
   s=s+(1./((i**2)+(j**2)))
 end do
end do

print*, s
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had initially been trying to reset s1 to 0 each iteration and had been getting a printout of 0, now I see that my issue came from needing to make one of the terms real